# GIMP: Toggle show/hide all non print extras

Tags: gimp

In GIMP, is there a way to quickly toggle all visible guides, grids, selection boxes, etc that are cluttering the display? I'm hoping there's something that's one key stroke instead of the way I currently do it which is to toggle 3-4 different things through the `View` menu every time I want a clean preview of my work.

In Photoshop it's `View -> Show -> None/All` [[source]](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/show-or-hide-non-printing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zach-Saucier mentioned it appears there is no single magic shortcut for doing this.

However an alternative I found was to create a new view (`New->View`) and then hide all the grids, guides, selection, etc in that view. Then toggle between the two views.

Answer (score 2):

You can view [the default keyboard shortcuts](http://www.gimpusers.com/gimp/hotkeys) and see that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> toggles the guides and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> toggles the rulers. There are many others, but I can't find one that removes them all in one command (other than going full screen using <kbd>F11</kbd>).

If you want to change the keyboard commands so they're the same as PS's, you can use [this library](http://epierce.freeshell.org/gimp/gimp_ps.php) to make them the same, but I still don't see one to toggles all the menus at once.

Comment: Hmm that shortcut isn't working for me in GIMP 2.8.14

Comment: @LeifGruenwoldt I revised my answer, I was looking at the wrong resource before :)

Comment: Thanks @Zach-Saucier. I ended up posting an answer of my own I found which will do the trick for me.

Comment: @LeifGruenwoldt I assume using F11 doesn't count?

Comment: fullscreen toggle? Nah.